# 'object-fit' in FF does not show properly

Tags: html, css, image, firefox

I am using rounded thumbnails on my page, but since the last update the `'object-fit:cover;'` does not show properly,

My images are pushed horizontally or vertically depending the original image. My **CSS** is very easy for this, it shows fine in **Chrome**.

What is wrong? Thanks.

```
border-radius:100%;
object-fit:cover;
```

Comment: Please see how to create an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you may used instead of `object-fit: cover`:

```
background-position: 100% 100%;
background-size: cover;
```

Or

```
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a background image, but an <img> nested in a <div> tag. It really fits the width and the height also, but earlier it worked perfectly, it cropped the image to the parent div's size...